# Annotation processor is not being invoked by the maven compiler plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, compiler-construction, annotations, processor

I have written my annotation processor as a separate maven project, it contains my custom annotation and its processor. I have added this project as a dependency to a project where the classes have been annotated with the custom annotation. I want this processor to be invoked as part of the maven build.

Following is the pom snippet -

```
<!-- Compiler configuration -->

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
       <path>
           <groupId>com.test.processor</groupId>
           <artifactId>processor</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.0</version>
       </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

<!-- dependency for processor project -->

 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test.processor</groupId>
        <artifactId>processor</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

But the problem is that, the annotation processor is not getting triggered. Am I missing something or doing anything wrong.

Kindly guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to a newer version of the maven-compiler-plugin.
I'm using 3.6.1 with the same configuration as you and it works.